# How do I reorder database by ID?

Tags: mysql, database

Currently my database is pretty messed up. The id's are not listed properly. I want them to be listed down permanently from 1 to 10. How do I do that? I want them listed from 1 to 10 permanently. Not just with

```
SELECT * FROM `accounts` ORDER BY `accounts`.`id` ASC
```

[image: http://prntscr.com/chu0nk]

Comment: [ORDER BY](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sorting-rows.html)? Or just click on ID in phpMyAdmin?

Comment: Make the ID field uniq and auto increment if that did not solve it just press that little  'id' link with your left mouse click. phpmyadmin shuld order them when you press it.

Comment: It is. Somehow phpmyadmin mixed it up.

Comment: You can use a SQL query to query all order by id:
SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY id ASC

Answer (score 1):

I know it's a process but you can make it this way first use this query to get data in order by id
 `select * from accounts order by id asc`
and insert the data in a dummy table and then just replicate the data of dummy table in your original table i.e. `accounts`

hope this will work for you